# How to change the link in the view by content type?

Tags: views, nodes

I change my question. Content type: How to add link field?

Comment: Short answer is yes.

Comment: @rooby may I know how?

Comment: Without having clear information about your situation it is bit hard to address the question straight. However you might be looking for something like this https://www.drupal.org/project/link. If you can give more information about the link (Eg: wether it is internal link or external. It may be a link to the node itself...), we can help more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can add the Link field by add a module called link module which will add a type called link in the add field drop down. for that you will need to install [Link module](https://www.drupal.org/project/link)

Hope this will help :)